# Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again

Tags: linux, bash, centos, repository

i have a problems with yum update httpd

my server is CentOS 5.11

i get this error :

```
[root@pbx5 ~]# yum install httpd
Loaded plugins: kmod
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')>
http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')>
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
[root@pbx5 ~]#
```

here my repo CentOS-Base.repo

```
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/i386/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/extras/i386/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment mirrorlist in **[base]**:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/i386/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

And check, if vault.centos.org is resolving properly:

```
$ dig +short vault.centos.org
 109.72.83.61
```

If it's not resolving, try add record manually:

```
echo "109.72.83.61 vault.centos.org" >> /etc/hosts
yum clean all && yum makecache
```

Comment: still same sir, i get this error


`Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirror.elastix.org/?release=2&arch=x86_64&repo=commercial_addons error was
[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')>
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: commercial-addons. Please verify its path and try again
[root@pbx5 yum.repos.d]#`

Comment: Now you have one more repository with the error. Domain **mirror.elastix.org** is not resolving. Run `grep -Rl mirror.elastix.org /etc/yum.repos.d/` and set **enabled=0** in repo-files, where this domain noted.

Comment: still same sir, this i get error `[root@pbx5 ~]# yum install httpd
Loaded plugins: kmod
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=x86_64 error was
[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')>
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
[root@pbx5 ~]#`

Comment: Looks like you have very old repos. Use HTTPS instead of HTTP.
Try change `http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org` by using https. Set mirrorlist to `https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org`
Also, I recommend you install CentOS 7, because CentOS 5 has reached EOL 2  years ago.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible. CentOS 7 uses *systemd*, so you need manually migrate all the data. We can fix all the errors in order you want to install httpd, but some software may be outdated.